Linenumber: Start to count with "Number" instead of 1
Doing this:
\begin{linenumbers}
line

line line

line line line
\end{linenumbers}

\resetlinenumber  
\begin{linenumbers}
bla

blabla
\end{linenumbers}

Gives us this
1 line
2 line line
3 line line line
1 bla
2 blabla

However deleting "\resetlinenumber" gives us
1 line 
2 line line 
3 line line line
4 bla
5 bla bla

But how is it possible that "bla" start with e.g. 7 instead of 1 or 4?
So i want this:
1 line 
2 line line 
3 line line line
7 bla
8 bla bla

BIG THANKS!

You can use \resetlinenumber[7] or \begin{linenumbers}[7].
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lineno}

\begin{document}

\begin{linenumbers}
line

line line

line line line
\end{linenumbers}

\resetlinenumber[7]
\begin{linenumbers}
line

line line

line line line
\end{linenumbers}

\begin{linenumbers}[7]
line

line line

line line line
\end{linenumbers}

\end{document}


